# How do I tell devise authentication to ignore IP address changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise with Rails3 for authentication, however due to the nature of the app the IP of the client changes. How do I stop Devise requiring the users session to be on a single IP. Obviously the cookie is persisting when the IP changes.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hmmm it looks like devise should persist as long as the session persists. Can you post your devise config? Any custom options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have `:rememberable` in your devise options some thing like:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

And in your migration you have something like this:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable
  t.confirmable
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable
  t.timestamps
end
```

Again the emphases is on rememberable for the model and migration.
Docs are [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/frames).

Comment: Sorry, I was talking complete gibberish but the doucments did help me figure out what the problem actually was. Thanks a lot.